# python suds - Insert raw xml node into factory-created object

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

In python suds, how do I insert a Raw XML node into an object created via the factory.create method, while still maintaining attributes?  Is there some _child field I could use?  Basically, how do I use an s:any child with Raw()?

What I need to send:

```
<web:Script Format="raw">
    <raw_xml_node foo="bar">stuff</raw_xml_node>
</web:Script>
```

I create the Script object with:

```
>>> scr = client.factory.create('Script')
>>> scr._Format = "raw"
>>> print scr
(Script){
    _Format = "raw"
}
```

Relevant WSDL:

```
<s:complexType name="Script">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:any/>
    </s:sequence>
    <s:attribute name="Format">
      <s:simpleType>
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="xhtml"/>
          <s:enumeration value="raw"/>
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
    </s:attribute>
</s:complexType>
```

Comment: Why do you need to to this? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Basically, it needs to be passed to a function, like client.service.addScript(Script scr).  And I have the raw XML, which needs to be put into this Script object.  I do not have the ability to change the server, and it works fine in SoapUI.